# all wcf methods return void while calling from windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

when i have add the wcf service refrence in my windows phone 8 project , all the service methods have return void ,

i have use all Asyn and await

```
 public async void getdata()
        {
            ServiceReference1.BALClient service = new ServiceReference1.BALClient();
            var list=await service.Get_ListAsync("SQL");      
        }
```

> Error Error   Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable
>                    Cannot await void

and when i use Asyn and completed with eventArgs that is also not working

```
    public async void getdata()
      {    
            service.helloAsync();
                   service.helloCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.helloCompletedEventArgs>(service_helloCompleted);

      }
   public void service_helloCompleted(object sender, viceReference1.helloCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
                   string i = e.Result;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some doing search and search i got the solution

make sure that webservice have full address with machine IP.

```
> http://localhost:6060/Web_new
```

make ip address instead of localhost

```
> http://192.160.16.1:6060/Web_new
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something similar to:

```
ServiceReference1.BALClient.Get_ListCompleted +=  new EventHandler<Get_ListCompletedEventArgs>(ListFromClientCompleted);
ServiceReference1.BALClient.Get_ListAsync("SQL");
```

then in another method

```
void ListFromClientCompleted(object sender, Get_ListCompletedEventArgse)
    {
        if (e.Error==null)
        {
            //Do something with e.Result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some platforms, the WCF client will not create task-returning ([TAP-style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) asynchronous methods. Instead, it creates [EAP-style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

I recommend you create a TAP wrapper for your EAP methods, [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP). I believe the reason your current attempt is not working is because you are assigning the handler after starting the operation.

Comment: can you make 1 example please, i have unable to understand the blog that you had recommend

Comment: There's an example in the [last link in my answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP). I'm not sure if I can make it any clearer than that example.